# Send JSON via HTTP Request via post method

Tags: ios, json, xmlhttprequest

I`m trying to send JSON via HTTP Request:

Here is my code :

```
NSString* locations = [kBaseURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:kLocations];

BOOL isExistingLocation = location._id != nil;

NSString *urlStr = isExistingLocation ? [locations stringByAppendingPathComponent:location._id] : locations;
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]; //1

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";


NSData* data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[location toDictionary] options:0 error:NULL]; //3
request.HTTPBody = data;

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; //4

NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) { //5
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", response.description);

        NSArray* responseArray = @[[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL]];
       [self parseAndAddLocations:responseArray toArray:self.objects];
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

and here is the dictionary which I`m trying to send...

http://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/5YUE

EDIT: I configured the server to return the HTTPBody received and the return is

```
{}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the response is currently?

Comment: the response is the new entry in MongoDB Collection..but ir returns only _id that is the default field from a new entry in a collection in MongoDB....It occurrs because the JSON is going wrong. When I put the JSON in Javascript it works great...then the Web service is working fine...the problem is in my iOS request

Comment: @rob the image is in the link : [link](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/5YUE). And the server just return the JSON received...and is returning {}